# android push notifications coming twice

Tags: android, notifications, push

I am using notification.compat builder to build the notification. In the notify method I am passing id as 1. The control is coming only once in the broadcast receiver. But I am able to see two notifications in the notification bar. But when I am giving id as 0 in the notify method, notification is coming only once. But in this case, on clicking the notification the main activity of the app is always opened, even though some other activity is mentioned in the pending intent. What can be the reason of two notifications coming? Please help

Even when I am using notificationManger.cancelAll(), its not working

Here is my code :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
 .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
 .setContentTitle(ctx.getString(R.string.gcm_notification))
 .setContentText(message)
 .setContentIntent(intent)
 .build();
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notificationManager.cancel(0);
notificationManager.cancel(1);
notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Comment: show us how do you create the notification object.

Comment: Please share some code to solve your problem..

Comment: As you can see in my code, I have tried to cancel the notifications from both the ids i.e. 0 and 1 before calling the notify method. Still the result is same.